Not Getting any response From the REST api Node js
As title suggests I am not getting any response any my api rather it just keep on loading. For some reason my middleware is not triggered. For example from the below code I tried to console log random text but the value is not printed.
export const login = asyncErrorHandler(
  async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    console.log("hawrgag")
    
    if (!email || !password) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler("Enter all the details", 400));
    }

    if (!validateEmail(email)) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler("Please enter correct email", 400));
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler("User doesn't exists", 400));
    }

    const pass = verifyPassword(password, user.password);
    if (!pass) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler("email or password is incorrect", 400));
    }

    const data = {
      user: {
        id: user._id,
      },
    };

    const authtoken = generateToken(data);

    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, authtoken });
  }
);

It looks like the middleware is not called. I don't know where is the problem.
This is the asyncErrorHandler
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import { ControllerType } from "types/controllerType";

const asyncErrorHandler = (func: ControllerType) => {
  return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    return Promise.resolve(func(req, res, next)).catch(next);
  };
};

export default asyncErrorHandler;

This is my ControllerType
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

export type ControllerType = (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => Promise<void | Response<any, Record<string, any>>>;

This is my route file
import express from "express";

import { sendOTP, verifyOTP, signup, login } from "../controller/auth";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/send-otp", sendOTP);
router.post("/verify-otp", verifyOTP);
router.post("/signup", signup);
router.post("/login", login);

export default router;

And This is my index.ts file
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from "express";
import http from "http";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";

import connect from "./db";
import auth from "./routes/auth";
import user from "./routes/user";
import { errorhandling } from "./middleware/errorhandling";

dotenv.config();

const app: Express = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

const { PORT } = process.env;
const server = http.createServer();

connect();

app.use("/api/v1/auth", auth);
app.use("/api/v1/user", user);

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

Please help me where I went wrong.

You probably meant to pass the Express app to the HTTP server:
const server = http.createServer(app);

You can also just leave out http.createServer() completely, as Express will do that for you:
const app: Express = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

connect();

app.use("/api/v1/auth", auth);
app.use("/api/v1/user", user);

const { PORT } = process.env;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

